# Can I change database folder (.meteor/local/db)?

Tags: meteor

How can I change folder that contains mongodb files (`.meteor/local/db`)? Is there any ENV value?

I don't want to set `MONGO_URL`. I just wanna change folder.

Comment: Why? now impossible;  **options.appDir** https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/5535d4cc98840f99b867f0d4132079484b16dbba/tools/run-mongo.js#L642

Comment: Why would you want to do this, what problem do you want to solve?

Comment: Hmm. I have 2 apps connected to one db. For me `MONGO_URL` working fine. But for other team members (not meteorjs dev), I'm just kinda lazy to setup things for them :).

Comment: The thing you want is just like @YaşarİÇLİ said not possible if ur lazy (just like the most of us are) you could get register a free online mongodb instance and let everyone connect to that database.

Comment: Another use case would be for developers on windows using a dockerized meteor... Mongo can't get the lock if the path is shared with the host.